# Statistics for conditions with different number of levels

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I have measured the brain activity in a group of 10 subjects who had to perform a task in `real` and `imagined` conditions, the task is about stopping a hand movement when a stop signal appears. In the `real` condition I have 2 sub-levels (succesfully stopped `SS` and unsuccesfully stopped `US`), and I don't have these sub-levels in the imagined condition, there aren't any overt response to classify as SS or US in imagination.

My main objective is to compare the brain activity (using event related potentials) between the `real` and the `imagined`conditions, a simple t-test can do it. But this activity is modulated if the task is `SS` or `US`, and taking both only as the `real` condition dilutes some effects.

Is there any way to compare between: `imagined-real`, `imagined-SS`, `imagined-US` and `SS-US`?

I think that a one-way ANOVA with four levels is not a good way to compare these data...

Comment: What are your questions of interest? What exactly do you want to find out?